# What other RDBMS should my open source Java persistence library support

Tags: java, open-source, rdbms, jooq

I'm releasing a new version of [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org), a Java persistence library built on top of JDBC. Currently, I support these seven RDBMS:

- Oracle
- MySQL
- Postgres
- H2
- HSQLDB
- DB2
- SQLite (experimental)

With jOOQ I want to provide both broad and robust RDBMS support. This means I have to be quite selective in order to provide robustness with my integration tests. At the same time, I have to meet end user needs supporting important databases. I expect my end users to heavily rely on their databases. jOOQ is not an OR-mapper. Au contraire, jOOQ embraces vendor-specific features such as [stored procedures](http://java.dzone.com/articles/2011-great-year-stored), so the underlying database really matters to me.

In the next release, I want to add more RDBMS support. For example:

- MS SQL
- Derby

What would you suggest, and why? Please explain based on objective grounds and cite your references.

**UPDATE**:

The following RDBMS are now supported. Thanks again for feedback

- CUBRID
- Derby
- Ingres
- SQL Server
- Sybase (both SQL Anywhere and ASE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Ring Bearer's suggestion of sybase, and your listing of MS SQL and Derby, the only big ones left are Ingres and Firebird.

IBM also has a second database, Informix, but I know absolutely nothing about it besides the name :)

Answer (score 2):

**Sybase** - why? a lot of systems still run sybase; especially in Healthcare domain.
Sybase is industry class and feature rich. +1 for the project. I went through the site and I am impressed.

Comment: +1 for the healthcare hint. Thanks. I have it on the roadmap https://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/jooq/ticket/97. But currently it is a low priority. Healthcare... That's a big industry with lots of legacy code, where jOOQ might fit in well. How do you know? Are you working in that field?

Comment: I can tell you the Practice Management Software my dentist runs uses Sybase.

Comment: @Lukas, yes I work in healthcare field and I know at least 3 core applications here  depend on Sybase.